# Dancer::Plugin::Email module - Is data tainted?

Tags: perl, webserver, dancer

When using the [Dancer::Plugin::Email](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer::Plugin::Email) module,should you check the user input for malicious data or is the input automatically tainted etc?

Although Dancer specific, does in the general case that the server runs as root and the untrusted user input passes a system("rm -rf *") or something along those lines that is then fed to the sendmail executable pose a risk and opens the can of worms?

Is that why it is recommended to run the webserver as a limited privilege user?

Comment: You should *always* sanitize user input, whether taint mode is enabled or not.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any way to use Dancer::Plugin::Email to run arbitrary commands, and if there was one, you'd probably find it in [Email::Sender](https://metacpan.org/pod/Email::Sender), which is what talks to `sendmail`. Running arbitrary commands by passing plain arguments to Email::Sender would definitely be a bug.

> should you check the user input for malicious data

No, you should check the user input meets the criteria you set.

The distinction is important.

For a route which causes email to be sent, make sure that as much data as possible comes from sources you trust (i.e. not the request), and only request/user user input where there's a good reason to.

> Is that why it is recommended to run the webserver as a limited privilege user?

It is good practice to execute code - especially public-facing web apps - with the minimum privileges, not because there are known security holes, but because there may be holes that you do not know about.